# The language of Turing machines that accept exactly $k$ inputs

Tags: computability, undecidability, decision-problem

For a fixed $k\geq 0$, let $X_k = \{\langle M\rangle\mid |L(M)|=k\}$, where $\langle M\rangle$ is the encoding of a Turing machine $M$ and $L(M)$ is the language $M$ accepts.  Is $X_k$ recursive, recursively enumerable or neither?

I think $X_k$ is NOT recursively enumerable because even if you generate every possible string, and test each one, if you find $k$ strings that M accepts, you still have to check every other string (in case $M$ accepts more than $k$ strings), which means your machine will loop indefinitely, and never find a yes-instance. However I'm not sure how you would show this, initially I thought I could reduce the NHP (Not Halting Problem) to L but that didn't go too well. Any ideas?

Comment: See this thread https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11181/how-to-show-that-a-function-is-not-computable/

Comment: and our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/847#847) I vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: another somewhat related thread: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/17889/show-that-a-language-is-re-or-recursive

Comment: Related question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54254/proving-a-language-is-neither-recursively-enumerable-nor-co-recursively-enumerab

Answer (score 1):

Hint: to decide whether $M$ halts on input $w$, consider a new machine $M'$ that rejects every input except $w$ and simulates $M$, otherwise. That's not quite the answer but it should get you close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please see a related question. [Proving a language is neither Recursively Enumerable nor co-Recursively Enumerable](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54254/proving-a-language-is-neither-recursively-enumerable-nor-co-recursively-enumerab)

Though the question talks about $|L(M)| = 1$ the solution is general enough for any $|L(M)|$.

We can show $L_u \leq X_k$ as following.
We reduce $\langle M,w\rangle$ to a Turing machine $M'$ as follows:
$M'$ rejects all inputs other than $w$ and some other $k-1$ distinct strings.
$M'$ accepts the other $k-1$ distinct strings as mentioned before. If the input is $w$ then it runs as Turing Machine $M$ on $w$. This gives us $\langle M,w\rangle \in L_u$ iff $M' = f(\langle M,w\rangle) \in L$.

In fact we can prove that $X_k$ is neither RE nor co-RE. This can be done by taking $k$ other distinct strings than $w$ in the above reduction.